# Web hosting vs web service hosting

Tags: web-services, wcf, mobile, web, hosting

Just want to ask. I just created my web service which a mobile phone consumes, I'm running it on my local host and tested it on my own network and works pretty well.

Now, I'm thinking to upload the service somewhere over the host service provider.

Does web hosting services like godaddy and similar also provides web service hosting? I mean, if I build a website I can upload it on the web hosting site and manage it there, is it the same when I upload my Service?

If not, where's the best place where I can upload my service and test it there?

The service I created is in WCF

Thanks in advance anyone. :)

Comment: ["WCF"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation) generally means using the Microsoft ASP.NET (or maybe Mono) stack. What is "the service" that is being uploaded? It can *only* be used with an applicable server/host/environment.

Comment: Thanks for the immediate response. Its in WCF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you have 2 options for hosting a WCF service in IIS being published to the public:

1. create a Windows VM on typical VM providers like Godaddy, Azure or Amazon etc, and follow the instructions from respective provider about publishing Websites. Remember, WCF is running in the app pool, while IIS Website is responsible for listening requests and delivering responses for WCF.
2. In Azure, you could publish WCF through Worker Role. Search "wcf azure worker role" you will find plenty docs and tutorials.

After all, best place depends on your best skills and best budgets etc. Option 1 and 2 could be enough for starting points.

Comment: ZZZ. Thanks for this information. I dont have experience in publising service over the service providers, in my work we have our own domain server, that's the only experience I got so far, this will be the first time that I will use services from the third party. I find it a little expensive hosting applications developed using Microsoft products. I might change the service from WCF to PHP soon, anyway this is a personal project that I creating right now. :)